# Is scipy cdist() efficient?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html

I looked at  the implementation of this function, and I saw that it's just using loops. I'm interested only in the `euclidean / sqeuclidean` option.

As you can see in this article: http://nonconditional.com/2014/04/on-the-trick-for-computing-the-squared-euclidian-distances-between-two-sets-of-vectors/ , the output of this function can be done with matrix multiplication which seems to be more  efficient for me rather than looping.

Can somebody clear me this issue?

Here is the c code implementing the result output:

```
for (i = 0; i < mA; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < mB; j++, dm++) {
        u = XA + (n * i);
        v = XB + (n * j);
        *dm = seuclidean_distance(var, u, v, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look again: it's for loops *only* if the metric is an user-provided callable (in which case the only possible implementation is a loop), not when it's one of the known metrics of which euclidean is one.

Comment: @pv Thanks, I'll check this right now

Comment: The final answer probably is that it's still for loops, but written in C.

Comment: @pv , thanks again. Still looks like a look for me :)




`for (i = 0; i < mA; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < mB; j++, dm++) {
            u = XA + (n * i);
            v = XB + (n * j);
            *dm = seuclidean_distance(var, u, v, n);
        }
    }`

Comment: But it doesn't answer my actual question..

Comment: I posted on a similar issue in this thread https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/dan_patterson/2015/10/09/before-i-forget-16-numpy-vs-scipy-making-a-point I was interested in what could be done in under one second... my take in the paragraph beginning  OK... are you missing something like me?   I kind of get why efficiency is important, but I am more interested in total time to perform a task for a given condition. PS I am sure my code isn't optimized, nor have I used the best match.

Comment: Numerical stability is a good reason not to do things the way the article you link suggests, for reasons similar to why variance is not calculated with [the naive textbook algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance).

Comment: Are you asking why a loop in C is faster than a loop in Python?

Comment: @ali_m No, I'm asking why isn't this function implemented with matrix multiplication but loops.

Comment: @Jaime I didnt understand. It seems that using matrix mult and vector computation will be faster than looping

Comment: Try this yourself on a Python interpreter: `a = 1e15 +1; b = 1e15`, now compute `(a - b)**2` and `a**2 + b**2 - 2*a*b`. Surprised? You have just witnessed (lack of) numerical stability at work. So unless you are certain this type of problem cannot happen in your dataset, it is better to sacrifice performance for correctness.